# Custom exception not being caught in Django 1.4

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm using Django 1.4.5 and Python 2.7.6.

I'm defining a custom exception error in exceptions.py :

```
class RegEmailError(Exception):
    pass
```

I'm also raising it in another module:

```
if not "success" in response:
    from registration.exceptions import RegEmailError
    raise RegEmailError(response)
```

I'm trying to catch it in another module which calls a function in 2nd module:

```
from registration.exceptions import RegEmailError
try:
    self._send_confirmation()
# RegEmailError is not getting caught here..
except RegEmailError as e:
    print "send_confirmation: e", e
    mail_admins("error", "Error sending out email(s): %s" % e)
    if not fail_silently:
        raise e
```

The exception does not get caught, instead the traceback is shown in the browser:

```
File "/Users/akulakov/envs/regproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/akulakov/envs/regproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 48, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/akulakov/envs/regproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in dispatch
return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/akulakov/projects/regproj/htdocs/../htdocs/registration/views.py", line 122, in post
return super(RegisterView, self).post(request, *a, **kw)
File "/Users/akulakov/envs/regproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 172, in post
return super(BaseCreateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/akulakov/envs/regproj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 138, in post
return self.form_valid(form)
File "/Users/akulakov/projects/regproj/htdocs/../htdocs/registration/views.py", line 111, in form_valid
formset.save()
File "/Users/akulakov/projects/regproj/htdocs/registration/formset.py", line 107, in save
registrant.send_confirmation()
File "/Users/akulakov/projects/regproj/htdocs/registration/models.py", line 1011, in send_confirmation
self._send_confirmation()
File "/Users/akulakov/projects/regproj/htdocs/registration/models.py", line 1049, in _send_confirmation
util.send_email(tpl_key, '', to, subject, form_data)
File "/Users/akulakov/projects/regproj/htdocs/registration/util.py", line 122, in send_email
equeue.queue(template_key, to, from_, subject, form_data, **kw)
File "/Users/akulakov/projects/regproj/htdocs/registration/emailqueue.py", line 81, in queue
raise RegEmailError(response)
```

I haven't run into this before.. I tried debugging and it looks like 'e' is the correct exception of the type RegEmailError, and there's only one RegEmailError
defined in the codebase, in one single place.

Comment: Did you try setting `DEBUG` to `False`? Your exception is probably catched by Django before you can handle it.

Comment: Django isn't supposed to do that, but I tried setting debug to False, the exception is still not getting caught.